# Issue with detecting an empty index in a Java char array

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

I am currently working on a project where I am running into an issue with detecting an empty index in a char array. The issue is that it doesn't detect whether or not there is an empty index in the array. I have tried detecting different things people have said where the placeholders for an empty char but none of them seem to work.

Here are the different things I have tried:
0, '0', 'u0000', '\u0000\, and null.

```
public class TestArrayChecker {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char array1[] = new char[] {'F', 'P', 'S', 'R'};
    char array2[] = new char[] {'S', 'P', 'O', 'R'};
    char c1 = '\u0000';
    char arrayOfCorrect[] = new char[array1.length];
    int correct = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int close = 0;

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (getColorAt(i, array1) == getColorAt(i, array2)) {
            correct++;
            arrayOfCorrect[index] = getColorAt(i, array1);
            index++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int n = -i; n < 4 - i; n++) {
            if(getColorAt(i, array1) == getColorAt(i + n, array2)) {
                for (int f = 0; f < arrayOfCorrect.length; f++) {
                    System.out.println(getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect) + " " + f);
                    System.out.println(arrayOfCorrect.length);
                    System.out.println(getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect) != c1);
                    if (getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect) != c1) {
                        System.out.println(getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect) + " " + f);
                        System.out.println("No Void in this array");
                        if(getColorAt(i, array1) != getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect)) {
                            System.out.println("This number is close: " + getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect));
                            counter++;
                            break;
                        }   
                    } else {
                        counter++;
                        System.out.println("We got here!");
                    }
                    if (counter == 4) {
                        close++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(arrayOfCorrect[0] + " " + arrayOfCorrect[1] + " " + arrayOfCorrect[2] + " " + arrayOfCorrect[3]);
    System.out.println(correct);
    System.out.println(close);
    System.out.println(counter);
}

public static char getColorAt(int index, char array[]) {
    // TODO: Fill-in code to return the color at a particular position
    return array[index];
}
```

}

This is the main part of the code that is not working:

```
if (getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect) != c1) {
    System.out.println(getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect) + " " + f);
    System.out.println("No Void in this array");
    if(getColorAt(i, array1) != getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect)) {
        System.out.println("This number is close: " + getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect));
        counter++;
        break;
    }   
} else {
    counter++;
    System.out.println("We got here!");
}
```

Here is the output of the console, the last two numbers are supposed to print out 1 and 4.

```
P 0
4
true
P 0
No Void in this array
R 1
4
true
R 1
No Void in this array
This number is close: R
P 0
4
true
P 0
No Void in this array
This number is close: P
P 0
4
true
P 0
No Void in this array
This number is close: P
P R  
2
0
3
```

I haven't removed all of my debug coding so please ignore that.
Thanks all for the help.

Comment: What do you mean "issue"? Do you get an error? Not the desired output? (If yes to either please [edit] your question and include the error/desired and current output)

Comment: Is `arrayOfCorrect` supposed to hold the matching letters in the position they were in the original arrays? (i.e. `[blank, 'P', blank, 'R']`)

Comment: arrayOfCorrect is just supposed to hold the letters that where already used.  (i.e. ['P', 'R', blank, blank]).  I know that the index variable I am using only gets increased after I created the array, but I don't think that is what is causing the issue.

Comment: What is the `counter` variable counting?

Comment: The counter variable is counting to see whether the char that is currently being looked at is contained in the arrayOfCorrect, sorry for my bad variable names, I was throwing things together at the end.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but isn't 3 the right output? You compare every element in the first array with each element in the second. So `F` will be compared with every letter in the second array and not match, `P` will compare and match once (`counter=1`), `S` will compare and match (`counter=2`), and finally `R` will loop and match, making `counter` 3

Comment: I was thinking that if there are two empty index's in my array, the counter should go to 2 from that, and then it would count to make sure that it doesn't = S & R, which would bring it to 4.  Correct me if I did something wrong in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm, okay. First of all, the issue isn't in detecting an empty char, I've tested it myself with this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char array[] = new char[10];

    int emptyCounter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 0) {
            emptyCounter++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(emptyCounter);
}
```

and I get an output of 10, as I left all chars empty.

Now, looking at your code, we can see why "getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect) != c1" will always be true : you break out of the for loop before it can encounter an empty string. You've got "arrayOfCorrect = ['P', 'R', empty, empty].

This is the part of your code that makes it so :

```
if(getColorAt(i, array1) != getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect)) {
    System.out.println("This number is close: " + getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect));
    counter++;
    break;
}
```

As you iterate through array1 with i, the condition is true when i is equal to 0 and 2. As we can see by your results, f is never going higher than 1 but is not the source of the problem.

As we go higher to get to the source of the problem, we come across this :

```
for (int n = -i; n < 4 - i; n++) {
    if(getColorAt(i, array1) == getColorAt(i + n, array2)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Btw, this isn't a good practice... this is like doing 2 + 10 - 10 + 2 = 4. As far as I can see, this would do the same work :

```
for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
    if(getColorAt(i, array1) == getColorAt(n, array2)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And it is now more easy to understand what you are trying to do here.

So, for every char in array1, you check every char of array2 until you find a correspondence. So basically, the condition will be true only 3 times : when array1[1] = array2[1], array1[2] = array2[0] and array1[3] = array2[3].

When i = 1, "getColorAt(i, array1) != getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect)" is true when f = 1 ('P' != 'R') and you exit the nested loop there.

When i = 2, "getColorAt(i, array1) != getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect)" is true when f = 0 ('S' != 'P') and you exit the nested loop there.

When i = 3, "getColorAt(i, array1) != getColorAt(f, arrayOfCorrect)" is true when f = 0 ('R' != 'P') and you exit the nested loop there.

So yeah, counter++ gets called only 3 times and you never encounter an empty char.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That really helps.  Now that I know what is happening, I can fix that issue.